# Extract data frame columns based on multiple criteria on column names

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to subset a data frame based on multiple column name criteria. I have a data frame as below:

```
id  team_col_code1   team_col_code2 ... team_col_code78   Gender State team_cost_code1   team_cost_code2 ... team_cost_code43
```

I am trying to subset this data frame such that the new dataset contains only columns containing column names containing the word `"col"` or `"id"` or `"Gender"`.

I am able to create a subset based on column names containing the keyword col as shown below

```
new_Df <- df[grep("col", names(df))]
```

I am not sure how to include the other two columns `id` and `Gender`, into this subset such that the new dataset looks like this below

```
id  team_col_code1   team_col_code2   ... team_col_code78   Gender
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi toy dataset from UCLA online repository

Comment: @ZheyuanLi fixed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be as straightforward as

```
df[c("id", grep("col", names(df), value = TRUE), "Gender")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to work this way:

```
df[,grepl("col|id|Gender",colnames(df))]
```